# How to fix String including double quotation is breaking html markup in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Please consider the following code:

```
{assign var="test_var" value="\"Think win-win.\" - A quote by whom? » MCQ Academy"}

<div class="story-data" data-title="{$test_var}"></div>
```

Result the broken html markup. please consider the screenshot:
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Guess, I got the solution. I need to use php `htmlentities()` function.

Example: `<div class="story-data" data-title="{$test_var|htmlentities}"></div>`.

More detail at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Feel free to write a batter solution if you have.

Thank you Guys.